# Python kivy lower widget position

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Hi I'm making a soccer game in kivy, and Whenever the game is over the soccer ball is in the middle of the screen but a little higher than I want it to be. How can I make it so that the soccer ball is a bit lower? Below is my code! Any help is appriciated! Thank You!

[image]

[image]

main.py

```
def game_over(self):
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball.center = self.root.center
    print("game over")
    self.frames.cancel()
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.start_button.disabled = False
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.start_button.opacity = 1
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.over.opacity = 1
```

gamescreen.kv

```
    Ball:
        source: "icons/ball.png"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 525, 525
        center_x: root.width / 2
        id: ball
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FloatLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html) then add customize the [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint) attribute to change ball location

**Example:**

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        myLayout = FloatLayout()

        myLayout.add_widget(Label(text="Hello, World!", pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.6}))

        return myLayout

MainApp().run()
```

**Example in KV Language:**

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

KV = """
FloatLayout:
    Label:
        text:"Hello, World"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.5, "center_y":.6}
"""

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.kv = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.kv

MainApp().run()
```

The result on both of codes is a label with text "Hello, World" on little upper than middle of screen

Comment: I just want my soccer ball to be in the same position as it was on the first image after the game is over

Comment: try adding this line to your `game_over` function:
`self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball.center_x = self.root.width/2`